# find LINQ queries in C# files

Tags: c#, linq

I need to find out `LINQ` queries while parsing `C#` files (with **Irony Codeparser**), because the parser does not support `LINQ` - therefore I have to exclude or modify such files, where `LINQ` occurs.

It would be no problem for me to go through the files with a `StreamReader` before parsing them or write modified copies of such files in the cache.

Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions for this problem?

Comment: what would be the purpose of doing that, if you don't want to parse those files..then why you have written linq based queries in your application..this is really a bad question..

Comment: This makes no sense. Also, SO is not a "do this code 4 me plz" site. At least try it yourself.

Comment: i did not write the application, it comes from other colleagues and i have no direct influence on the code. and so i'd need a possibility to erase the linq queries from the applications .cs files before parsing them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is not possible. How you will recognize `.Select(...)` is LINQ or Method of concrete class (with simple parser)?

Comment: my colleague gave me the hint that linq queries do follow a specific syntax. so i thought it might be possible to find out by a simple (or more complicated) regex?

Comment: You colleague lie to you. LINQ is not only "from a in b select a.c" but b.Select(a=>a.c) too and second one cannot be simple recognized